# Can I test Google+ rich snippet localy?

Tags: google-plus, social-networking, google-plus-one

I try to add google plus social share button. And want to customize share dialog. With facebook it's really simple -- I just change some arguments in function which create share button. But with google I should use Snippet API. I tried to do everything similar to [example](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/):
 but same standard dialog. Did I do something wrong or there is no ability to test this functionality local?

Comment: You should edit your question and insert the code that you are trying to use.

Comment: It will be better, if I copypaste code from example?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google crawler that populates the share box must be able to retrieve the page that you are referencing to be able to get the metadata. Google cannot crawl your local resources so you cannot directly test it that way. The Share buttons do not offer the ability to manually specify this data.

You could make a test copy and host it somewhere public to see how it renders. Another option would be to use a localhost tunneling service that you could use in your test URLs, but still be able to work locally.

Comment: Could you provide some link on example how to do localhost tunneling?

Comment: Check out localtunnel and pagekite as a few options.